# Multiple topics in one embedded yammer feed

Tags: embed, yammer

I want to embed a yammer feed on a sharepoint 2010 site and I want more than just one topic in it. I can set up a feed for #Yammer OR #YammerHelp but not both, at least not both in the same feed merged together. It seems they get embedded one after the other.

Is there no other way than to set up two feeds, one for each topic, in separate div-tags?

I use a content editor on a SharePoint 2010 page loading the standard script generated by Yammer.

Things I've tried:
feedId: "13267317",
feedId: "24515"

or
feedId: "firstid" "secondid",

All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do that with the current API. If you retrieved the messages from the REST API directly you could combine the two feeds, sorting by `created_at`, but not via Yammer Embed.